# Assigning Custom Setting value to Custom object Field

Tags: customsetting, wrapper-class

```
    /***********Custom setting **********/
Map<string, CountryCO__c> codes = CountryCO__c.getAll(); 
        string pb;
        list<string> pb1=new list<string>();

           for (string key: codes.keyset())
          {
                CountryCO__c code = codes.get(key);
               pb=code.Country_code__c ;
                 pb1.add(pb);
               } 

List<CountryListWrapper> CountryList= new List<CountryListWrapper>(); 

 List<Country__c> countrynew = new List<Country__c> ([Select Countrycode,price,state from Country__c ] ) ; //Custom object

      for(Country__c c: countrynew ) {  

              CountryListWrapper cl = new CountryListWrapper();

                cl .Countrycode = c.Country_code__c ;
                cl .Prodprice uctCode = c.price__c ;
                cl .state = c.state__c ;
                CountryList.add(cl );

           }
/*******Wrapper class*********/
 public class CountryListWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled public Integer Countrycode {get;set;}
 @AuraEnabled public Integer price {get;set;}
 @AuraEnabled public Integer state {get;set;}
}
```

I have created a custom setting with two fields(Country,Country Code).How to create a map with these two fields,so that I can take key's value and assign it to a wrapper class variable?The variable in wrapper class is assigned to a list containing custom object fields. Of-which one field in custom object is Country Code,which should be assigned with custom settings Country code field value.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm)? You will get examples of how to retrieve values from custom setting and assign it to any variable/field you want.

Comment: Based on your edit and your comment, I'm really not sure what you're asking. Your code as presented here will not compile for a variety of reasons. Would you take a minute to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to make this question clear and specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can get most of the way there with built-in [Custom Settings methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm).

If you utilize the Name field on your custom setting for the country code and, say, `Country_Name__c` for the name, you can call

```
Map<String, My_Custom_Setting__c> myMap = My_Custom_Setting__c.getAll();
```

Then your Map will have the country codes as its keys, and the Custom Settings objects as its values, so you can just do

```
myMap.get('US').Country_Name__c
```

to get a name.

For bonus points, wrap this in a utility class to make it easy to just call

```
SomeUtilityClass.getCountryNameForCode(someCode);
```

But this saves you the need to iterate and build your own Map.

Comment: Thanks Much.I have added sample of my code.Can you please tell me where to add the custom setting value so that it can change country code in custom object.

Comment: For instance in my custom object the value in country code is displayed as Country1, Country2....In custom settings I have assigned value like Country1 is 001,Country2 is 002.,etc., Now i wanted this code to be displayed.Please help me.